# How to correct malloc error in c++? when appending character

Tags: c++, malloc

```
void append(char* &s, const char& ch)
{
      /*
       Appends the character ch to the cstring s.
       That is ch is added to the end of s making sure the resulting s is a valid cstring
       The parameter s is assumed to be a dynamic array 
       
       */
      int len = cstrlen(s);
      int newLen = len + 1;
      char *C = new char[newLen + 1];
      C[len] = ch;
      C[newLen] = '\0';
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
      C[i] = s[i];

      delete [] s;
      s = C;
      
      return;
}
```

This is the my output window

```
Testing append function
----------------------
Appending ch='v' to s2="" gives s2="v"
Appending ch='x' to s2="v" gives s2="vx"
Appending ch='i' to s2="vx" gives s2="vxi"
Appending ch='r' to s2="vxi" gives s2="vxir"
Appending ch='i' to s2="vxir" gives s2="vxiri"
Appending ch='u' to s2="vxiri" gives s2="vxiriu"
Appending ch='u' to s2="vxiriu" gives s2="vxiriuu"
Appending ch='o' to s2="vxiriuu" gives s2="vxiriuuo"
Appending ch='s' to s2="vxiriuuo" gives s2="vxiriuuos"
Appending ch='b' to s2="vxiriuuos" gives s2="vxiriuuosb"
Appending ch='y' to s2="vxiriuuosb" gives s2="vxiriuuosby"
Appending ch='u' to s2="vxiriuuosby" gives s2="vxiriuuosbyu"
Appending ch='w' to s2="vxiriuuosbyu" gives s2="vxiriuuosbyuw"
Appending ch='j' to s2="vxiriuuosbyuw" gives s2="Assignment 3 Tester(34580,0x1000efe00) 
malloc: *** error for object 0x1007040d0: pointer being freed was not allocated
Assignment 3 Tester(34580,0x1000efe00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Assignment 3 Tester(34580,0x1000efe00) malloc: *** error for object 0x1007040d0: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

As you can see code is working fine for some iterations but then there is `malloc` error.
I have never encountered such a thing, Can someone explain what is happening or is the code wrong?
The code making the call is:

```
            //Test append function
      cout << endl << "Testing append function";
      cout << endl << "----------------------" << endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      {
            ch = rand() % 26 + 97;
            cout << "Appending ch='" << ch << "' to s2=\"" << s2 << "\" gives s2=\"";
            append(s2, ch);
            cout << s2 << "\"" << endl;
      }
```

Note- I use Xcode. The line below was red. I don't know what it means but maybe it gives you some clue.

`->  0x7fff202554c8 <+151>: movq   0x5fec07d9(%rip), %rax    ; (void *)0x00007fff88a5aa30: __stack_chk_guard` `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code making the `append` calls?

Comment: Thanks for this tidbit, but we still don't see the `s2` definition. Is this something that you allocated with `new` ?

Comment: ```s2``` is an empty cstring. with ```s2[0] ``` as a '\0'

Comment: unless you have something like `char* s2 = new char[1]; s2[0] = 0;` you are not allowed to `delete[] s2;`

Comment: Thanks man I found the mistake.   I had initialised ```s2[0] = '\0'``` but when I changed it to ```s2 = new char('\0')``` it is working great.

Comment: That new only allocates memory of 1 byte which contains `\0`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: You can't `delete[]` memory that was allocated with `new`, only with `new[]`. Use `s2 = new char[1]; s2[0] = '\0';` instead. Is there a reason why you are not simply using `std::string` instead?